# Protecting <a href='{{ my_model.some_url }}'> in Django

Tags: python, django

In my Django template, I have a link like this:

```
<a href='{{ my_model.some_url }}'>
```

The `some_url` bit is a Django `URLField` that a user can influence.

Can this be exploited in any way? (What comes to mind is including a quote in the URL and then arbitrary HTML.)

What can I do to protect this code?

Comment: The field is automatically validated, it's a Django `URLField`. I'm concerned that there could be vulnerabilities despite the URL being a valid one.

Answer (score 2):

In general there are valid URL schemes that are dangerous. Most obviously `javascript:`, which as a pseudo-URL refers not to a new location, but to a command to execute on the current page. Allowing a `javascript:` URL to be added to your page means you have a cross-site scripting problem.

There are also other scripting aliases (`vbscript:`, `mocha:` et al), as well as `data:` and any number of arbitrary protocol handlers that third-party software might have installed at the client. So typically you need to whitelist URL schemes.

Django's default URLValidator for URLField does this, allowing only http, https, ftp and ftps links, so as long as you haven't replaced the validators it should be OK. (You may wish to do so, if that's not the set of schemes you want.) If you have any other means to populate the `some_url` field that doesn't go through the normal field/validator then you'll need to make sure that is validated too.

> (What comes to mind is including a quote in the URL and then arbitrary HTML.)

As long as you haven't disabled `autoescape`, the default HTML-escaping provided by `{{...}}` templating prevents that (it correctly encodes single quotes to `&#39;`).